# How to know where the value of a field is being stored in

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a `field_date` in a content type.

I want to do something like this on a `tpl.php`:

`$date->____________` (where the value of the field is being stored)

How can I know this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you are asking how to see what's available to you in a variable.

Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, and just use the [`dpm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) function:

```
dpm($variable);
```

It will use [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) to represent the data you pass and display it on the page. If it's an array, it will show you all the elements, same for objects and so on.